# Adjusting Gridbag layout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, gridbaglayout

I am trying to implement this layout using GRIDBAG layout in java

```
public static void addComponentsToPane(Container pane) {
        if (RIGHT_TO_LEFT) {
            pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
        }

        JLabel label1,label2,label3,result,title;
        JButton calculate_btn;
        JTextField side1,side2,side3;

    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    if (shouldFill) {
    //natural height, maximum width
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    }


        title = new JLabel("Area of Triangle");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = -1;
    pane.add(title, c);



    label1 = new JLabel("Side 1: ");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
         c.ipady = 20;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(label1, c);

        label2 = new JLabel("Side 2: ");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
         c.ipady = 20;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(label2, c);


        label3 = new JLabel("Side 3: ");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 3;
    pane.add(label3, c);

        side1 = new JTextField("   ");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(side1, c);

        side2 = new JTextField("Side 3: ");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(side2, c);

        side3 = new JTextField("Side 3: ");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 3;
    pane.add(side3, c);

    calculate_btn = new JButton("Calculate");
    //c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady = 30;      //make this component tall
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 5;
    pane.add(calculate_btn, c);

        result = new JLabel("Result displayed here");
    if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    }
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 20;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 7;
    pane.add(result, c);


    }
```

So the code above is basically just the components that will be added to a GUI, but I am not quite getting what I want, this is what I am trying to achieve

[image]

But this is what I am getting with the above code

[image]

So when I compile the above is what I endup with, also if possible I dont want the user to resize the window, I am guessing some boolean with one of the window properties..

Comment: `pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);` this code line is by `Darryl Burke` or `camickr`, especially by second of mentioned Swing Gurus have got a few examples about GBC on this forum,

Comment: GBC works only (correctly) only in the case that all columns are filled (use invisible JComponents), then you can use any of column for any of rows :-),

Comment: +1 for having a go at hand laying out `GridBagLayout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your are setting `ipady` which "stretches" your component vertically. You are probably looking for the `insets` property: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html#insets

Try using this:

```
c.insets = new Insets(10, 0, 10, 0);
```

Comment: what about the default size when the program initializes? it is coming out very small I want this fixed.

Comment: Also the TITLE of the application how to push it to all the way to the top?

Comment: @noobprogrammer Don't post additional questions in comments, rather post another question. Try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), this allow others to help you better and faster. You may want to look into JTextField.setColumns(int) and JFrame.pack(). You can also set an empty - border on the content pane of the JFrame (take a look at BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder()...

Answer (score 3):

Here's another approach using a `GridBagLayout` which results in...

[image]
[image]

```
public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new FormPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    protected static class FormPane extends JPanel {

        JLabel label1, label2, label3, result, title;
        JButton calculate_btn;
        JTextField side1, side2, side3;

        public FormPane() {
            // You may not need this, I needed it because the window packed to 
            // small on my mac ;)            
            setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            title = new JLabel("Area of Triangle");
            label1 = new JLabel("Side 1: ");
            label2 = new JLabel("Side 2: ");
            label3 = new JLabel("Side 3: ");
            side1 = new JTextField(4);
            side2 = new JTextField(4);
            side3 = new JTextField(4);
            calculate_btn = new JButton("Calculate");

            result = new JLabel("Result displayed here");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            add(title, gbc);

            gbc.weighty = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            add(label1, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(label2, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(label3, gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            add(side1, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(side2, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(side3, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 2;
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(result, gbc);

            gbc.gridy++;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
            add(calculate_btn, gbc);

        }

    }

}
```

If you want add space between the title and the fields and some `Insets`

```
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 8, 0);
add(title, gbc);

// Don't forget to reset them ;)
gbc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I just realised that the results should be displayed under the button.  Simple swap the lines `add(result, gbc)` and `add(calculate_btn, gbc)`, everything should remain the same

Comment: EXCELLENT! is there any way to set the size for the JFRAME and lock it with that sizes?

Comment: JFrame.setSize, be careful though, your working in a variable environment, where the font size, DPI and resolution are never the same, better to use pack to allow the frame to adjust to the preferred size of its content. I tend to add an empty boarder to many of my frames to give it some space around the content. To stop the user from resizing the frame, use JFrame.setResizable

Answer (score 2):

One issue I'm seeing with your code is that you're re-using the same GridBagConstraints object for all the elements you add, which is not recommended.

My advice would be to use a GUI builder like the ones available in NetBeans or Eclipse. Hand-coding GUIs in Java is very painful, and GridBagLayout in particular was pretty much designed for use in generated layout code.

Alternatively, use something like [TableLayout](http://xito.sourceforge.net/projects/tablelayout/) - or bite the bullet and [read up](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) on the intricacies of [GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html).

Comment: Reusing the same GBC is not a problem. It may look ugly, but that's not the issue here.